# Bounds on Lyapunov Singular Values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Let $A$ be a square $n \times n$ real matrix, and consider the Lyapunov operator $L(X)$ defined by
$$
  L(X) := A^T X A - X \:.
$$
I am curious if there are any known lower bounds on the following quantity
$$
  \underline{\sigma} := \inf\{ \| L(X) \|_F : \|X\|_F = 1 \} \:,
$$
in terms of some properties of the spectrum of the $A$ matrix. 
Using the identity $\mathrm{vec}(A X B) = (B^T \otimes A) \mathrm{vec}(X)$, 
we can see that this is equivalent to computing the minimum singular value of the matrix 
$$
  A^T \otimes A^T - I \:.
$$
Weyl's inequality gives us a bound
$$
  \sigma_{\min}(A^T \otimes A^T - I) \geq 1 - \sigma_{\max}(A)^2 \:.
$$
But if $\sigma_{\max}(A) \geq 1$, then this bound is vacuous. I'm curious if we can say something under weaker conditions. Thanks!